# Download JSON Object as a file from Desktop Application (ElectronJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have designed application using `Node.js` and I have converted into Desktop Application using `ElectronJS`. Downloading JSON object as a file is not downloading automatically to my `downloads` Folder, Instead it is asking `Popup window` to choose the path to save the file.
Below Code I have used:

HTML: `<a id="downloadAnchorElem" style="display:none"></a>`

```
var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + 
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(storageObj));
var dlAnchorElem = document.getElementById('downloadAnchorElem');
dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href",     dataStr     );
dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "scene.json");
dlAnchorElem.click();
```

If i run this code as a normal webapplication, it is downloading automatically whereas if i run the same on on Desktop Application using `ElectronJS` **NOT** downloading automatically. Kindly tell me why this is happening and Alternative solution is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

**[electron-dl](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl)** is your friend!. As its description goes in the github, it really simplifies file downloads for your Electron app.

Here is an example how you can initiate the download.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const {download} = require('electron-dl');

ipcMain.on('download-btn', (e, args) => {
    download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), args.url)
        .then(dl => console.log(dl.getSavePath()))
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

Hope this helps!